# Flutter (stable) run for Android throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)

Tags: android, macos, flutter

Does anyone know about this issue? I run `flutter run -v` on MacOS for an physical Android device, get exception says `throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)` and blah blah blah.

[Attached log of `flutter run -v`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/files/4605106/flutter_run_v.log)

My flutter is on stable channel and healthy, any help would be very appreciate!

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G103, locale en-CN)
    • Flutter version 1.17.0 at /Volumes/Transcend/Development/flutter
    • Framework revision e6b34c2b5c (7 days ago), 2020-05-02 11:39:18 -0700
    • Engine revision 540786dd51
    • Dart version 2.8.1


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Volumes/Transcend/Development/AndroidSDK
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.45.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.10.1

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • SM G9500               • 988a1b474239545746                       • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)
    • Capt. Michael’s iPhone • 14717dae7626a115db93783c0f4a386e6c51783e • ios           • iOS 12.4.5

• No issues found!
```

Comment: I am also facing this issue.

Comment: @BilalRabbi , if you use flutter_facebook_login, try to remove it.

Comment: I got the same issue. discovered that my pspdfkit trial password has expired. did update new password solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after removed `flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0` from *pubsepc.yaml*.